# Tuckey urlRewriteFilter use-query-string="true" not working?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, web, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to use Tuckey urlRewriteFilter to rewrite any URLs to https://, while preserving any query string parameters that were appended to the URL.  My urlrewrite.xml file currently looks like

```
  <urlrewrite use-query-string="true">

<rule>
    <note>
        The rule means that requests to /test/status/ will be redirected to /rewrite-status
        the url will be rewritten.
    </note>
    <from>/test/status/</from>
    <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/rewrite-status</to>
</rule>

<rule match-type="regex">
   <condition type="header" operator="notequal" name="X-Forwarded-Proto">^HTTPS$</condition>
   <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">/station/StationPingServlet</condition>
   <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">/station/StudioPingServlet</condition>
   <from>^.*$</from>
   <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://%{server-name}%{request-uri}</to>
</rule>

<outbound-rule>
    <note>
        The outbound-rule specifies that when response.encodeURL is called (if you are using JSTL c:url)
        the url /rewrite-status will be rewritten to /test/status/.

        The above rule and this outbound-rule means that end users should never see the
        url /rewrite-status only /test/status/ both in thier location bar and in hyperlinks
        in your pages.
    </note>
    <from>/rewrite-status</from>
    <to>/test/status/</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

I thought that use-query-string="true" would accomplish this, so

http://server.com/test.jsp?company=3&id=1

will be rewritten to

https://server.com/test.jsp?company=3&id=1

but this doesn't seem to be happening.  What happens is that

http://server.com/test.jsp?company=3&id=1

is rewritten as

https://server.com/test.jsp

Am I doing anything wrong?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 8):

Since [version 4.0](http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd) , it is possible to use `qsappend` attribute for `to` property. The value of `qsappend` is by default false, so you have to enable it.

So the solution can be,

```
<rule match-type="regex">
   <from>^.*$</from>
   <to type="permanent-redirect" qsappend="true" last="true">https://%{server-name}%{request-uri}</to>
</rule>
```

**UPDATE:** For versions below 4.0, you can use `?%{query-string}` at the end of your URL

```
<rule match-type="regex">
   <from>^.*$</from>
   <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://%{server-name}%{request-uri}?%{query-string}</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: The "qsappend" attribute is only valid from the version 4.0.
It doesn't exist in 3.2.
cf. http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd

Comment: What is the alternative for 3.2?

Comment: Updated the answer. Thnx.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it appends the ?  even when there isn't a query string...

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical, if by default this `qsappend` attribute is set to `true`? In a reverse proxy, you don't have to "activate" the query-string for redirection either, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<rule>
   <from>^(.*)$</from>
   <to last="true" type="permanent-redirect">https://%{server-name}$1</to>
 </rule>
```

Be sure to add ' **`use-query-string="true"`** ' on the urlrewrite tag